# SV_WC_Payment_Form_Handler when activating payment gateway

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using 'WooCommerce Elavon Converge Gateway' when I enabled this then error comes on checkout

Uncaught ReferenceError: SV_WC_Payment_Form_Handler is not defined

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this error as well. Turns out there was a function trying to optimize all the sourced javascript tags with 'defer'. I figured out a way to exclude files with 'woocommerce' and 'jquery' in there filenames and it fixed the problem.

One way to check on if this an issue it to right click on your page, select 'View source', when the source page opens use CTRL+F to search for '

If you have a website optimizer plugin added to your site, you might see if you can change the settings, disable it, or perhaps try a different plugin. These optimizers will try to make the site load faster by telling the browsers to load certain code later. And as a result the optimizer may have indiscriminately told critical code to be loaded much later than was needed, by accident.

Comment: This was useful. For me it was an async js plugin applying defer to everything.

Answer (score 0):

After disabling the optimization plugin "Autoptimize" in my WordPress Plugins, My Checkout page loaded correctly and the SV_WC_Payment_Form_Handler error went away!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution if you have Cloudflare caching/DNS management, you can set a rule  to not cache `/cart` and `/checkout` under Caching > Cache Rules in your account.

The rule would be:

`URI Path > Contains /cart` or
`URI Path > Contains /checkout`

[image]

Then select **Bypass Cache**

[image]

Click the **Deploy** button.